# How to check which version of Keras is installed?

Tags: keras

Question is the same as the title says.

I prefer not to open Python and I use either MacOS or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Python library authors put the version number in `<module>.__version__`. You can print it by running this on the command line:

```
python -c 'import keras; print(keras.__version__)'
```

If it's Windows terminal, enclose snippet with double-quotes like below

```
python -c "import keras; print(keras.__version__)"
```

Comment: For python3 version use this ....```python3 -c 'import keras; print(keras.__version__)'```

Answer (score 42):

You can write:

```
python
import keras
keras.__version__
```

Answer (score 19):

The simplest way is using `pip` command:

```sh
pip list | grep Keras
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple command to check keras version:

```
(py36) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda custom (64-bit) 

>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
>>> keras.__version__
'2.2.4'
```

Comment: OP said Linux or MacOS.

Answer (score 6):

pip show tensorflow

```
C:\>pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.4.1
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for 
everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Requires: google-pasta, wheel, absl-py, flatbuffers, numpy, astunparse, opt- 
einsum, six, termcolor, typing-extensions, wrapt, grpcio, tensorboard, 
protobuf, tensorflow-estimator, gast, h5py, keras-preprocessing
Required-by:
```

Same way can try for

```
pip show keras
```

If it is installed then it will provide the details.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using standalone Keras (`pip install keras`), then it's straightforward:

```py
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

For Keras Core, the preview version of Keras 3 (`pip install keras_core`), it's simple as well:

```py
import keras_core as keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

If you are using tf.keras—the Keras implementation bundled with TensorFlow (`pip install tensorflow`)—then the Keras API version depends on the TensorFlow version. You can try this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.keras.__version__)  # works for TF version 1.9 to 2.13
```

If the TensorFlow version is 2.14 or above, then unfortunately `tf.keras.__version__` is undefined.

Here's the mapping between TensorFlow version and Keras API version:

| `tf.__version__` | `tf.keras.__version__` |
| --- | --- |
| ≤1.8.* | undefined |
| 1.9.* | 2.1.6-tf |
| 1.10.* | 2.1.6-tf |
| 1.11.* | 2.1.6-tf |
| 1.12.* | 2.1.6-tf |
| 1.13.* | 2.2.4-tf |
| 1.14.* | 2.3.0-tf (if tf2.enabled(), else 2.2.4-tf) |
| 1.15.* | 2.3.0-tf (if tf2.enabled(), else 2.2.4-tf) |
| 2.0.* | 2.3.0-tf (if tf2.enabled(), else 2.2.4-tf) |
| 2.1.* | 2.3.0-tf (if tf2.enabled(), else 2.2.4-tf) |
| 2.2.* | 2.3.0-tf (if tf2.enabled(), else 2.2.4-tf) |
| 2.3.* | 2.4.0 |
| 2.4.* | 2.4.0 |
| 2.5.* | 2.5.0 |
| 2.6.* | 2.6.0 |
| 2.7.* | 2.6.0 |
| 2.8.* | 2.6.0 |
| 2.9.* | 2.6.0 |
| 2.10.* | 2.6.0 |
| 2.11.* | 2.6.0 |
| 2.12.* | 2.6.0 |
| 2.13.* | 2.6.0 |
| 2.14.* | undefined |
| 2.15.* | undefined |

Answer (score 1):

For terminal, run: (Change with `python3` for version of *Python3*)

```
python -c 'import keras; print(keras.__version__)'
```

Or if you want to check inside code, include:

```
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```