# How do I know which version of the Keras API is implemented in tf.keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In the standard implementation of Keras, one can get the API version using [`keras.__version__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46086030/1735003).

However, there is no `tf.keras.__version__`.

So how do I check the version of the Keras API implemented in `tf.keras`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply run this code

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

which is compatible with TF v1.8.0.

Comment: On TF 1.8 it returns `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.tools.api.generator.api.keras' has no attribute '__version__'`. Which version of TF are you running?

Comment: You're right. In 1.8.0, I checked and it didn't work, but this was working in previous versions. So I tried `from tensorflow.python import keras; print(keras.__version__);` It printed `2.1.5-tf`

Comment: Yes, this one works — and is shorter that my version. If you edit your solution I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

This has recently been updated:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf.keras.__version__)
2.1.6-tf
>>> print(tf.__version__)
1.12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the version of Keras implemented in `tf.keras` using

```
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import __version__ as tf_keras_version
print(tf_keras_version)
# 2.1.5-tf (in TF 1.8)
```

It seems that from TF 1.9 on, it will actually be accessible as `tf.keras.__version__`, as it should.